# What does the "Extra Toggle" cheat do?

Tags: lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes

I'm seeing stuff elsewhere about how it unlocks all characters during free play or allows you to play as special characters, but I still have access to all characters with it disabled, and I can't see  how to access these extra character's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked this out. The critical difference is between the characters you can select from the menu (hold Y-button on X-box) which (LB/RB on X-Box), which allows you to cycle through a small subset of characters.

As [this answer says](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/91989/15477) the Extra Toggle allows you some extra odd-ball characters, **but only affects the LB/RB set**.

Answer (score 1):

Extra Toggle gives you access to some bonus characters on certain levels that you can't play as otherwise. The characters usually don't have any real advantages; they're just there for fun.

Comment: Any examples? I'd like to see the effect to make sure I recognize it.

Comment: @deworde: I've heard that some examples are Penguin robots and an Old Lady. In Star Wars I know that you could play as a Womp Rat which was fun. I can't find a list for Batman 2, but [here's a list of the characters in other games.](http://legogames.wikia.com/wiki/Extra_Toggle)